# Multiple files upload Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I want to upload multiple files in Laravel but it's not working I tried in my controller
Edit:  I means page refresh but no error or registred data in the db
I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk5usyevYj0

```
public function storescan(Request $request){


          $this->validate($request,[
          'file' => 'required|file|mimes:gif,jpg,png,jpge,jpeg|max:102048'
        ]);


       $files=$request->file('file');
          foreach($files as $file){
            Document::create([
              'doc'=>$file->getClientOriginalName(),
              'path'=>$file->store('public/storage'),
              'support'=>$request->input('support'),
              'ecole'=>$request->input('ecole'),
              'jour'=>$request->input('jour'),
              'cycle'=>$request->input('cycle'),
              'type'=>'Image',
              'niveau'=>$request->input('niveau'),
              'matiere'=>$request->input('matiere'),
              'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id 
            ]);
          }  
        return redirect()->route('prof.document.create')->withMessage('✅ Image(s) ajoutée(s) avec succès!');

      }
```

And here is my route and formular

```
 Route::post('/professeur/myDoccy/scan/create','DocumentController@storescan')->name('prof.document.createscan');
```

Formular everything is correct I minimized the code and left only the input file

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form"  action="{{ route('prof.document.createscan') }}" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
           {{ csrf_field() }}

 <label class="purple" >Charger l’image </label><br/>
            <input  required type="file" multiple name="file[]" accept='image/*' class="form-control-file border-or m-1" >
          </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "but it's not working" means? Please be more specific

Comment: ah sorry I mean page refresh but no error or registred data in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check $errors variable (read more https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation).

You have problem with validation. You have rule

```
'file' => 'required|file|mimes:gif,jpg,png,jpge,jpeg|max:102048'
```

But it will work for single file. You have multiple of them, so it should be:

```
'file.*' => 'required|file|mimes:gif,jpg,png,jpge,jpeg|max:102048'
```

Also, you can use "image" rule instead of file with all mimes.

Comment: I never tried this is my first time knowing this Thank you so much this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting the validate part 
And adding to all fillable attributes in my model but still no validation possibility

```
class Document extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'doc','support','ecole',
              'path',
              'jour',
              'cycle',
              'type',
              'niveau',
              'matiere',
              'user_id'
    ];
}
```

function

```
public function storescan(Request $request){

       $files=$request->file('file');
          foreach($files as $file){
            Document::create([
              'doc'=>$file->getClientOriginalName(),
              'path'=>$file->store('public/storage'),
              'support'=>$request->input('support'),
              'ecole'=>$request->input('ecole'),
              'jour'=>$request->input('jour'),
              'cycle'=>$request->input('cycle'),
              'type'=>'Image',
              'niveau'=>$request->input('niveau'),
              'matiere'=>$request->input('matiere'),
              'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id 
            ]);
          }  
        return redirect()->route('prof.document.create')->withMessage('✅ Image(s) ajoutée(s) avec succès!');

      }
```